# Does the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}[f(n)-f(n-1)]=0$ imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exists?

Tags: calculus

I have a function $f(n)$ that is defined when $n$ is a non-negative integer. $f(n)$ is always a real number such that $1<f(n)<2$. Because of how this function is definied, I cannot prove the limit directly, but I was able to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}[f(n)-f(n-1)]=0$$It makes sense to me that this might prove the existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$, but I do not know for sure if that is true. Is there some way to prove that this is true? And if so, is the fact that $f(n)$ is bounded between 1 and 2 necessary to the proof?

Comment: Modify a periodic function like $\sin x$ to conclude that this does not imply the existence of the limit.

Comment: Do you want to consider $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)$? You said that the function is defined on non-negative integer, not whole $\mathbb{R}$. So this seems more reasonable.

Comment: I apologize, I did not realize the use of x implies all real numbers. I will change this.

Comment: Would it be helpful to add more context relating to the problem I am dealing with?

Comment: If you can bound the decay by a function that vanishes sufficiently fast, then it has a limit.  For example, if $|f(n)-f(n-1)|\leq A/n^2$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and for some constant $A>0$, then it has a limit.  More generally, it has a limit if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |f(n)-f(n-1)|<\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:
No. Let us think about a condition $0\leq f(n)\leq1$ (we can move and scale the values).
Then we start:

up: $f(1)=0$, $f(2)=1$,

down: $f(3)=1/2$, $f(4)=0$,

up: $f(5)=1/4$, $f(6)=2/4$, $f(7)=3/4$, $f(8)=4/4=1$,

down: $f(9)=7/8$, $f(10)=6/8$, $f(11)=5/8$, $\ldots$.
Can you see the pattern?

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look for another way to prove the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Example:

$\sin(2\pi x)$.

Comment: The asker has clarified/modified the post.